# JEST with Express does not finish

Tags: node.js, jestjs, axios, nanoexpress

I started to write tests with Jest of (nano)express application. The test starts the server at `beforeAll()` and closes it at `afterAll()`. I can see that the code is executed, but the JEST process does not end.

test.js

```
test('end to end test', async () => {
    const polls = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/bff/polls/last`);
    console.log(polls.data);
    expect(polls.data).toBeDefined();
});

beforeAll(() => {
    app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0')
        .then(r => logger.info("Server started"));
});

afterAll(() => {
    if (app.close())
        logger.info("Server stopped");
});
```

Output from `npm run test`

```
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.625s
Ran all test suites.
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

When I run with `jest --config jest.config.js --detectOpenHandles` the test does not finish as well but there is no error and I need to kill it anyway.

The complete source code is there: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/blob/master/infrastructure/test/api.int.test.js

I have tested separatelly outside of the tests that nanoexpress will terminate the process with `app.close()` call. So it is JEST related.

Update: the same behaviour with promises

```
test('end to end test', () => {
    const polls = axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/bff/polls/last`);
    return expect(polls).resolves.toBeDefined();
});
```

**Update:**

Here you can find minimum reproducible repository: https://github.com/literakl/nano-options.git

I have switched from Axios to GotJS and the trouble is still there. When I run the test with `npm run test` from command line now, it fails with:

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 20000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 20000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error
```

When I start the test from WebStorm there is no error but the process keeps running.

Comment: Hi @Leos, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the error you are facing? I tried simplifying the code in your repo and I am not able to reproduce it (it works fine for me).

Comment: I am trying to reproduce both JEST issues I face now.

Comment: You can find it there: https://github.com/literakl/nano-options.git

Comment: do you mind updating the reproducible repo with GotJS based code or is it okay for an answer based on the current axios based code?

Comment: I would accept any answer. The networking library is not relevant for this trouble. BTW I use the last NodeJS 12 version. I think that version 13 behaves the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

My initial thought was that this is a [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) related issue but it appears that jest `testEnvironment` has to be set to `node` in order for Axios to run propertly using the `axios/lib/adapters/http` adapter. You can check a related issue here ["detect jest and use http adapter instead of XMLhttpRequest"](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1180#issuecomment-375093333).

1. Set `testEnvironment: 'node'` inside `jest.config.js`.
2. Update `create user` test to run the `done` callback function at the end:

```
describe("user accounts", () => {
    test('create user', async (done) => {
        // let response = await axios.get(`${API}/users/1234`);
        let response = await axios.get(`${API}/users/1234`, getAuthHeader()); // TODO error with Authorization header

        expect(response.data.success).toBeTruthy();
        expect(response.data.data).toBeDefined();
        let profile = response.data.data;
        expect(profile.bio.nickname).toMatch("leos");
        expect(profile.auth.email).toMatch("leos@email.bud");

        // Call done here to let Jest know we re done with the async test call
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: @LeosLiterak please try my new answer. I got the test running and jest exiting at the end.

Comment: I tried with my main repository without success. But I use Got insytead of Axios now. https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/tree/master/infrastructure/test

Comment: Yes that uses the `done` callback as my proposed code. The problem is not with `axios` but that the async test is not calling `done` callback with your test. All async tests have to call `done` callback at the end. You can check it to this clone of your repo https://github.com/clytras/nanoexpress-jest

Comment: I have tested done earlier, but I have identified the root cause for my main repository - mongo DB client was not closed. Together it works now. I will write my answer for other people fighting with similar problem and how to resolve it. Thank you

Comment: fix commit: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/commit/2b0d8b66b67d2ef0601355528d44cc3f9ed3215a

Comment: Nice catch there. Every opened handle has to be closed at the end. That's why you must include as many information as posible to your question when having a problem like this. I've had the exact same issue a while ago when testing some MySQL bindings with Jest and that was the problem.

Comment: Calling `done()` in the Jest async test is just redundant. It's simply enough to return the promise from the test function or just to use an async/await (as you already do).

Comment: That is true @SlavaFominII; there is even a note into Jest documentation stating that calling `done` when returning a promise will result in an error; I should probably refactor this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause was an open handle of mongodb client. How did I find it?

1) install leakes-handle library

```
npm install leaked-handles --save-dev
```

2) import it to your test

```
require("leaked-handles");
```

3) the output

```
tcp handle leaked at one of:
    at makeConnection (infrastructure\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:274:20)
tcp stream {
  fd: -1,
  readable: true,
  writable: true,
  address: { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 54963 },
  serverAddr: null
}
```

If you cannot find the root cause, you can kill the JEST explicitelly with

```
jest --config jest.config.js --runInBand --forceExit
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another reason for me. I was using Puppeteer and because my target element was hidden the screenshot method threw error:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        executablePath: chromiumPath
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(`file://${__dirname}\\my.html`);
const element = await page.$("#my-element");

// This may throw errors
await element.screenshot({path: snapshotFileName});
await browser.close();
```

So, I made sure that the `browser.close()` was called no matter what:

```js
try {
    await element.screenshot({path: snapshotFileName});
} finally {
    await browser.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works for my integration testing with Express, Nodejs, and Jest. Nothing special in package.json either: "test": "jest --verbose". Cheers

```
afterAll( async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.close();
    jest.setTimeout(3000);
});
```

Tests:       6 passed, 6 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.818 s, estimated 5 s
Ran all test suites matching /users.test.js/i.